# How to change printed variable in php?

Tags: php, caching

I put a sub file in the main file, but the sub file affects the variables in the main file.

Simple example:

**In my code include can not be before echo.**

Index.php

```
<?php

    $heading= "Heading";

    echo "<h1>$headeing</h1>";

    include_once('specific_data.php');

?>
```

Specific_data.php

```
$heading = "Specific Heading";
```

Real output:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Desired output:

```
<h1>Specific Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can reate MVC stracture 
For example

index.php

```
include_once 'view.php';

$heading='custom head';

return view('specific_data.php',compact('heading'));
```

view.php

```
function view($file,$vars=[])
{

   extract($vars);
   include_once $file.'.php';

}
```

specific_data.php

```
<h1>this variable get from index and will render <?=$heading?></h1>
```

Exec index.php from browser you will see following code

```
this variable get from index and will render custom head
```

Answer (score 1):

You echo the value before include os before you assign the new value

try move the echo   after the include

```
 <?php

   $heading= "Heading";



   include_once('specific_data.php');

   echo "<h1>$headeing</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: As I wrote In my code include can not be before echo.

Comment: the  you ca't show a value that is not know  ...  you firts need the assignment and after this you can show/echo/print  the value  ..,. coding is not magic..